# Looping through arrays within classes to create wordpress metaboxes

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, meta-boxes

I have a class sitting in my Wordpress functions.php. Eventually it's going to end up in the plugins folder but one step at a time. Below is a foreshortened version of it:

```
class metaboxClass {

    $them_meta_boxes = array (
        array (
            "1a_myplugin_box_id_1",
            "1b_Custom Meta Box Title 1"
        ),
        array (
            "2a_myplugin_box_id_2",
            "2b_Custom Meta Box Title 2"            
        )
    );

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_box' ) );
    }

    public function add_meta_box( $post_type ) { 

        $post_types = array( 'page', 'my_cpt' );
        if ( in_array( $post_type, $post_types )) { // *** IF $POST_TYPE IS IN THE ARRAY $POST_TYPES

            foreach ($this->them_meta_boxes as $level_1) {

                add_meta_box (
                foreach ($this->level_1 as $level_2) {
                    echo $level_1 . ",";
                }
                array( $this, 'render_form'),
                $post_type
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the above, I'm trying to construct various iterations of the add_meta_boxes function using the information  in the array.

I've a feeling that there are a number of issues here and I'm kind of going through them one at a time but the first is that when an object is instantiated from  the class I get: "syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' ". I know this is usually caused by a missing semi-colon. In this case the semi colon is present and correct. I've a feeling it's something to do with the placement of the array  but I'm getting similar problems when it's placed outside. Can anyone give me any pointers - I'm pretty new to the world of OO PHP and also to really getting my hands dirty with the wordpress backend so any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Stef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a `foreach` loop as a parameter to a function. Construct your argument string first and then pass the constructed string as an argument to your `add_meta_box` function.

Even then though, I'm not sure what you are trying to call since your `add_meta_box` function only takes one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted for the record... ended up something  like this:

```
class initialise_meta_boxes {

    public $meta_boxes_array = array (
        array (
            "1a_myplugin_box_id_1",
            "1b_Custom Meta Box Title 1",
            "render_dropdown"
        ),
        array (
            "2a_myplugin_box_id_2",
            "2b_Custom Meta Box Title 2",
            "render_dropdown"       
        )
    );


    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save' ) );
    }

    public function make_meta_box($meta_id, $meta_title, $meta_callback) { 
        return add_meta_box ($meta_id, $meta_title, $meta_callback, $post_type );
    }

     public function add_meta_box( $post_type ) { // *** $post_type is global variable!!!
        $post_types = array( 'page', 'my_cpt' );
        if ( in_array( $post_type, $post_types )) { // *** IF $POST_TYPE IS IN THE ARRAY $POST_TYPES

            foreach ($this->meta_boxes_array as $value) {
                    $this->make_meta_box($value[0], $value[1], array( $this, $value[2]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```